# Forming Case statements in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to form a Case statements for the following queries:

```
select 
Distinct T from iwa b 
where exists (
 select * from iwa where T=320 and art=1234
) 
and exists (
 select * from iwa where T=450 and art=1234 and art=b.art
);

select T from iwa where T=320 where art=1234;

Select T from iwa where T=450 where art=1234;
```

`T` is a column name, `iwa` is a table name and `art` is an input.
I should get an output from all the above queries checked.

Comment: Question is not clear, provide some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Your query statemets in `exists` is not correlated for main query. If it exists you will have full scan.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand really what you trying to achieve. Maybe you need something like this?

```
select T 
from iwa 
where (T=320 and art=1234)
or (T=450 and art=1234)
```